# print method is behaving strangely for dataframes

Tags: r, rstudio, pander

When I try to display the contents of a dataframe, I am getting some strange output (see the screenshot below). I am using `head()` here but the behavior is the same for any display of a dataframe.

[image: Screenshot of RStudio]

The behavior only seems present in RStudio. As shown below, my base installation of R behaves as expected.

[image: Screenshot of base R installation]

My sessionInfo is as follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
_LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252_, _LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252_,     _LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252_, _LC_NUMERIC=C_ and _LC_TIME=English_United     States.1252_
attached base packages:
_stats_, _graphics_, _grDevices_, _utils_, _datasets_, _methods_ and _base_
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
_digest_0.6.3_, _pander_0.3.8_ and _tools_3.0.1_
```

Any thoughts as to what is going on?

UPDATE

In response to Hong Ooi, I am displaying the results of `getAnywhere("print.data.frame")[1:2]` below.

```
$`package:base`
function (x, ..., digits = NULL, quote = FALSE, right = TRUE, 
    row.names = TRUE) 
{
    n <- length(row.names(x))
    if (length(x) == 0L) {
        cat(gettextf("data frame with 0 columns and %d rows\n", 
            n))
    }
    else if (n == 0L) {
        print.default(names(x), quote = FALSE)
        cat(gettext("<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)\n"))
    }
    else {
        m <- as.matrix(format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, 
            na.encode = FALSE))
        if (!isTRUE(row.names)) 
            dimnames(m)[[1L]] <- if (identical(row.names, FALSE)) 
                rep.int("", n)
            else row.names
        print(m, ..., quote = quote, right = right)
    }
    invisible(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000009f8e570>
<environment: namespace:base>

[[2]]
function (x, ..., digits = NULL, quote = FALSE, right = TRUE, 
    row.names = TRUE) 
{
    n <- length(row.names(x))
    if (length(x) == 0L) {
        cat(gettextf("data frame with 0 columns and %d rows\n", 
            n))
    }
    else if (n == 0L) {
        print.default(names(x), quote = FALSE)
        cat(gettext("<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)\n"))
    }
    else {
        m <- as.matrix(format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, 
            na.encode = FALSE))
        if (!isTRUE(row.names)) 
            dimnames(m)[[1L]] <- if (identical(row.names, FALSE)) 
                rep.int("", n)
            else row.names
        print(m, ..., quote = quote, right = right)
    }
    invisible(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000009f8e570>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: Looks like something is overriding the default `print.data.frame` method when Rstudio is running. Type `getAnywhere("print.data.frame")` to see what's being called.

Comment: The output in the RStudio window is the output you get from "pander". Try detaching the "pander" package and see if the problem persists. (That said, I use "pander" and have never noticed this problem, hence my comment and not an answer.)

Comment: @AnadaMahto, I have tried detaching "pander" with no luck. I did notice that pander was mentioned in the sessionInfo() output as "loaded via a namespace (and not attached):" but am not sure how to interpret it. I am adding a pander tag to this post...

Comment: It is indeed a Pandoc table produced by `pander` - I have no idea when RStudio guys decided to set that function of mine as `print.default` :) I am really interested in what's going on in the background and why `pander` was loaded. Isn't there something special in your `.Rprofile`?

Comment: @daroczig, nothing apparent in my ``.Rprofile``. Everything is commented out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which one worked, I upgraded RStudio from v0.97.551 to v0.98.447 and upgraded R from 3.0.1 to 3.0.2. One of these upgrades appears to have fixed my problem and my dataframes are printing normally again :)

Answer (score 0):

You are in an RScript window. The double asterisks and `&nbsp` are RMarkdown "punctuation". The sessionInfo() detail is not going to be as helpful in understanding RStudio's behavior as would be describing exactly the sequence of actions you executed with the GUI.